# Finding side of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

> In a parallelogram $ABCD$, the bisector of angle $ABC$ intersects $AD$ at $P$ where $PD=5, BP=6$ and $CP=6$. Find $AB$.

I tried equating areas and heron's formula but no luck..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$\angle{ABP}=\angle{CBP}=\angle{BPA}=\angle{BCP}$$
from which we know that $\triangle{ABP}$ and $\triangle{PBC}$ are similar.

Let $AB=x$. Then, $AP=x,BC=x+5$ to have
$$AB:PB=PB:CB\iff x:6=6:x+5.$$

Comment: It is obvious. But how to use it?

Comment: @Roman83: I added some details.

Comment: Your solution is much better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $AB=x$. It is easy to see that $AB=AP$. Let $h$ be the distance between $AD$ and $BC$.

By Pythagorean theorem (try to find out the right triangles I am using), we have $$h^2+\left(\frac{x+5}2\right)^2=6^2$$ and $$h^2+\left(5-\frac{x+5}2\right)^2=x^2.$$

We have $x^2+5x-36=0$. Hence, $x=4$.